# Can't get SVC Score function to work

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to run this machine learning platform and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 574 should be equal to 11, the number of features at training time
```

My Code:

```
from pylab import *
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np

X = list ()
Y = list ()
validationX = list ()
validationY = list ()
file = open ('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\csci4113\\project1\\whitewineTraining.txt','r')
for eachline in file:
    strArray = eachline.split(";")
    row = list ()
    for i in range(len(strArray) - 1):
        row.append(float(strArray[i])) 
    X.append(row)
    if (int(strArray[-1]) > 6):
        Y.append(1)
    else:
        Y.append(0)
file2 = open ('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\csci4113\\project1\\whitewineValidation.txt', 'r')
for eachline in file2:
    strArray = eachline.split(";")
    row2 = list ()
    for i in range(len(strArray) - 1):
        row2.append(float(strArray[i])) 
    validationX.append(row2)      
    if (int(strArray[-1]) > 6):
        validationY.append(1)
    else:
        validationY.append(0)

X = np.array(X)
print (X)
Y = np.array(Y)
print (Y)
validationX = np.array(validationX)
validationY = np.array(validationY)

clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X,Y)
result = clf.predict(validationX)
clf.score(result, validationY)
```

The goal of the program is to to build a model from the fit() command where we can use it to compare to a validation set in validationY and see the validity of our machine learning model. Here is the rest of the console output: keep in mind X is confusingly a 11x574 array!

```
[[  7.           0.27         0.36       ...,   3.           0.45         8.8       ]
 [  6.3          0.3          0.34       ...,   3.3          0.49         9.5       ]
 [  8.1          0.28         0.4        ...,   3.26         0.44        10.1       ]
 ..., 
 [  6.3          0.28         0.22       ...,   3.           0.33        10.6       ]
 [  7.4          0.16         0.33       ...,   3.04         0.68        10.5       ]
 [  8.4          0.27         0.3        ...,   2.89         0.3
   11.46666667]]
[0 0 0 ..., 0 1 0]
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-31c649fe24b3>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/csci4113/project1/program1.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/csci4113/project1')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/csci4113/project1/program1.py", line 43, in <module>
    clf.score(result, validationY)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 310, in score
    return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 568, in predict
    y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 305, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 474, in _validate_for_predict
    (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))

ValueError: X.shape[1] = 574 should be equal to 11, the number of features at training time


runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/csci4113/project1/program1.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/csci4113/project1')
10
[[  7.           0.27         0.36       ...,   3.           0.45         8.8       ]
 [  6.3          0.3          0.34       ...,   3.3          0.49         9.5       ]
 [  8.1          0.28         0.4        ...,   3.26         0.44        10.1       ]
 ..., 
 [  6.3          0.28         0.22       ...,   3.           0.33        10.6       ]
 [  7.4          0.16         0.33       ...,   3.04         0.68        10.5       ]
 [  8.4          0.27         0.3        ...,   2.89         0.3
   11.46666667]]
[0 0 0 ..., 0 1 0]
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-69-31c649fe24b3>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/csci4113/project1/program1.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/csci4113/project1')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/csci4113/project1/program1.py", line 46, in <module>
    clf.score(result, validationY)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 310, in score
    return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 568, in predict
    y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 305, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 474, in _validate_for_predict
    (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))``
```

Comment: what is X.shape and validationX.shape? you are reading out some 2 arbitrary files that we do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply passing **wrong object** to score function, [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.score) clearly states

> score(X, y, sample_weight=None)
>
> X : array-like, shape = **(n_samples, n_features)**
> Test samples.

and you pass **predictions** instead, thus

```
result = clf.predict(validationX)
clf.score(result, validationY)
```

is invalid, and should be just

```
clf.score(validationX, validationY)
```

What you tried to do would be fine if you use some **scorer**, and not **classifier**, classifier .score methods call .predict on their own, thus you pass **raw data** as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

as line 163 166 167
https://github.com/fatalfeel/hog_pca_svm_detection/blob/main/hog_pca_svm_detection.py

do train_test_split
svm.fit and score need array (xxx,xxx)
if single feature you can do [feature] make it to list array